# To find latest entry for a particular record in the unix file

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I have a file which has multiple entries for a single record. For example:

```
abc~20160120~120
abc~20160125~150
xyz~20160201~100
abc~20160205~200
xyz~20160202~90
pqr~20160102~250
```

The first column is record name, second column is date and third column is the entry for that particular date.

Now what I want to display in my file is the latest entry for a particular record. This is how my output should look like

```
abc~20160205~200
xyz~20160202~90
pqr~20160102~250
```

Can anybody help with a shell script for the same? Keeping in mind that I have too many records which needs to be sorted first according to their record name and then taking out the latest one for each record according to date.

Comment: I am planning to sort the file according to the record name and then split the file according to the date. When I have multiple files for each date, I can take the highest value for that file according to the date

Answer (score 2):

Sort the lines by record name and date reversed, than use the `-u` unique flag of sort to only output the first entry for each record:

```
sort -t~ -k1,2r  < input-file | sort -t~ -k1,1 -u
```